# Mahotas library for GLCM calulation and window size

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image, mahotas, glcm

I am using mahotas library to do texture analysis (GLCM) on a satellite image (250 x 200 pixels). GLCM calculations are carried out within a window size. So, for two adjacent positions of the sliding window we need to compute two co-occurrence matrices from scratch. I have read that I can set step size as well in order to avoid computing GLCM on overlapping areas. I have provided the code below.

```
#Compute haralick features
def haralick_feature(image):
    haralick = mahotas.features.haralick(image, True)
    return haralick


img = 'SAR_image.tif'
win_s=32 #window size
step=32 #step size

rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
array = np.zeros((rows,cols), dtype= object)
harList = []

for i in range(0, rows-win_s-1, step):
        print 'Row number: ', r
    for j in range(0, cols-win_s-1, step):
        harList.append(haralick_feature(image))

harImages = np.array(harList)     
harImages_mean = harImages.mean(axis=1)
```

For the code above, I have set the window and step size to 32. When the code finishes, I get an image with dimensions 6 x 8 (instead of 250 x 200), it makes sense as the step size has been set to 32.

So, my question is: By setting a step size (to avoid computation in overlapping regions as well as the code gets faster) can I somehow derive the GLCM results for the whole image with  dimensions 250 x 200 instead of having a subset of it (6 x 8 dimensions)? Or I have no option but looping over the image with the normal way (without setting a step size)?

Comment: Your code example is most likely incomplete: you always use the same argument to `haralick_feature`

Comment: Hi Luispedro, you are probably right, I might have missed to paste some bits of my code in here. I have created few different versions of this script (all scripts work fine) trying to work out how to get the GLCM results for the whole image (when setting a step size) instead of a small subject of it. If I do not set a step size, the process is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that using [`mahotas`](http://mahotas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) as the function which computes the **co-occurrence map** is not available in this library. An alternative approach to the extraction of texture features from the GLCM would consist in utilizing [`skimage.feature.graycoprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycoprops) (check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459493/sliding-window-in-python-for-glcm-calculation) for details).

But if you wish to stick to mahotas, you should try using [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) rather than a sliding window as it could speed up the scanning across the image. Please, be sure to read the caveat about **memory** usage at the end of the documentation. If using `view_as_windows` is an affordable approach for you, the following code gets the job done:

```python
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, util
import mahotas.features.texture as mht

def haralick_features(img, win, d):
    win_sz = 2*win + 1
    window_shape = (win_sz, win_sz)
    arr = np.pad(img, win, mode='reflect')
    windows = util.view_as_windows(arr, window_shape)
    Nd = len(d)
    feats = np.zeros(shape=windows.shape[:2] + (Nd, 4, 13), dtype=np.float64)
    for m in xrange(windows.shape[0]):
        for n in xrange(windows.shape[1]):
            for i, di in enumerate(d):
                w = windows[m, n, :, :]
                feats[m, n, i, :, :] = mht.haralick(w, distance=di)
    return feats.reshape(feats.shape[:2] + (-1,))
```

---

**DEMO**

For the sample run below I have set `win` to `19` which corresponds to a window of shape `(39, 39)`. I have considered two different distances. Notice that `mht.haralick` yields 13 GLCM features for four directions. Altogether this results in a 104-dimensional feature vector for each pixel. When applied to a `(250, 200)` pixels crop from a Landsat image, feature extraction finishes in around 7 minutes.

```python
In [171]: img = io.imread('landsat_crop.tif')

In [172]: img.shape
Out[172]: (250L, 200L)

In [173]: win = 19

In [174]: d = (1, 2)

In [175]: %time feature_map = haralick_features(img, win, d)
Wall time: 7min 4s

In [176]: feature_map.shape
Out[176]: (250L, 200L, 104L)

In [177]: feature_map[0, 0, :]
Out[177]: 
array([  8.19278030e-03,   1.30863698e+01,   7.64234582e-01, ...,
         3.59561817e+00,  -1.35383606e-01,   8.32570045e-01])

In [178]: io.imshow(img)
Out[178]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xc5a9b38>
```

[image: Landsat image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I appreciate it.